# IntentService JSON to Object Conversion

Tags: android

I am in the process of implementing an `IntentService` that I will use to perform RESTful web service calls, and then plan on using `sendBroadcast` to broadcast the results.

I receive JSON from the web service calls.

After I receive the JSON string, I'm not sure where I should actually parse the text and convert it into an object(s) (using GSON).  Would I be better off making all my domain objects `Parcelable`, and send the objects in the broadcast, or just send the JSON text, and convert them when I actually need the objects?  Any other advice?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's a matter of personal preference, but I just write my own classes to serialize and deserialize between JSON strings and model objects.  It might be a little bit of work to write the code as opposed to using some ORM like tool, but I find it to be very good for hunting down bugs or updating keys or nested hierarchies.

For each model object, I have a Translator class.  For example Thing and ThingTranslator.  This way, I can pass strings around between activities, and I have one single location where I can serialize and deserialize, so if there's ever anything wrong or something that needs to be updated (for ex, service changes object schema, etc) there's only one place to look.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not so much interested in the method for parsing JSON into objects, as I am about where I should perform the conversion, and in particular when using an IntentService.  Should I broadcast an object, and convert at the point of usage, or convert within the IntentSerice, and broadcast the object (or another approach).

Comment: I don't know if I understand the question.  If it's - should I go Parcelable or just serialize/deserialize my objects manually, I'd go with the latter.  The reason I do it as described is that I don't want every single model class I create to have the parceling logic in the class.  I am a strong proponent of the SRP and code simplicity, so my model objects are nothing but the model.  Serialization, validation, etc are all done externally.  Thing has properties and methods that represent Thing's purpose, ThingTranslator and ThingValidator and ThingProvider do their specific tasks, etc